# Can we send sms to other non android device using SmsManager?

Tags: android, sms

I am working on an android application , in which we are dealing with android sms service. I just want to know that is it possible to send sms to other non android device using the below method.

```
SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();

// HERE IS WHERE THE DESTINATION OF THE TEXT SHOULD GO

String number = "6508570720";

sm.sendTextMessage(number, null, "Test SMS Message", null, null);
```

OR

Do we have any other method to achieve this task.

Comment: yes this is the method to send SMS in android and it's not that it will only be send to Android devices ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SMS is not a device specific feature. It is provided and controlled by Telecom / Cellular service provider. So the code should send SMS to any phone from your Android device.

You may also try the following code:

```
String number = "6508570720";
String message = "hi there";

Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse( "sms:" + number ) ); intent.putExtra( "sms_body", message ); startActivity( intent );
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep, This should work for sending sms to non-android devices as well.